# How to get Csharp syntax tree from VS Code Extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, omnisharp

Is it possible to interact with the CSharp syntax tree from my own VS code extension? I have an extension which I made in Visual Studio proper which uses the Roslyn Syntax Tree to do a variety of code editing and sorting tasks and I want to migrate it to VS Code.

My naive assumption is that if I can get access to the OmnisharpServer object by reaching into the Omnisharp VS Code Extension I might be able to pull the relevant information out of there. I can get access to the extension itself by calling:

```
  let csextension = vscode.extensions.getExtension('ms-vscode.csharp')
```

But the extension itself doesn't expose much so I'm wondering if this is the correct methodology? If so, how do I get access to the running server from my own extension?

The only other strategy I have is to run a .net core exe which uses Roslyn to do the analysis, but this seems to be duplicating a problem which must be solved somewhere in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this without going through the Omnisharp VSCode Extension / its extension API (unless perhaps the server implements some custom interface). If an API doesn't already exist, you could consider creating a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues)?